# Centering entire page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to center my entire page using only CSS and it is proving more complicated than i first expected. Currently my code works in IE but not in Firefox which makes a change. The page can be seen [here](http://www.ronnieweb.co.cc/test/index.html). Below is the code portion involved:

```
#wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The structure of my HTML is:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    Gubbins in here.
</div>
</body>
```

It seems that in Firefox everything following the wrap div is be created outside of it. This is problem is resolved if i add a 'float: left' to the wrap div but then obviously everything floats left rather than center.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'wrap' is not a valid HTML element. The CSS selector #wrap targets ids, not tag names. +1 for John Sheehan

Comment: Sorry my mistake i my markup is in fact <div id="wrap">. I have edited above. Sorry.

Comment: http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your markup to

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    Gubbins in here.
</div>
</body>
```

EDIT: Looking at the link, you've already done that. You'll want to either add overflow:auto; to #wrap or add a clearing div at the end just before the closing tag on the wrap div.

Also, on your example page, the wrap div is missing its closing tag.

Comment: Actually looking again, on your example you're closing your div on the line that says </div> <!-- / navigation -->  your navigation UL is already closed, so this div is closing the wrap. move that closing tag to the end

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
body { text-align:center;}
#wrap {text-align:left; margin: 0 auto; width:960px;}
```

Then, let's examine this statement from your question:

> everything following the wrap div is be created outside of it

That's kind of the way it works.  *Don't put anything outside of your wrap div.*  Think of it as a surrogate body.

Comment: I thought text-align:center; does not work for anything other than text in FF?

Comment: margin: 0 auto; will work great for him once his markup errors are fixed

Comment: It's for IE, not firefox, to fix an IE css rendering glitch when trying to center content.

Comment: I have corrected the markup errors that have been pointed out. Yet i still had the problem. However after adding overflow: auto to wrap, everything is fine. Thank you.

Comment: IE6+ handles margin: 0 auto; without issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of your page - and it's fixed, you can use the following methodology.

- Contain your page content with a div (which will act as a wrapper)
- Give this 'wrapper' div a width of '**W**'
- Position the wrapper div using 'left: 50%;'

*now, utilising the fact that it's possible to have a negative margin...*

- Pull back the positioning of the wrapper div using 'margin-left: -(**W/2**);'