# Trying to center my web page

Tags: asp.net, css, margin, center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [page will not align center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279295/page-will-not-align-center)

I'm trying to center my web page using asp.net. When I use the `<center>` tag  it only centers the content placeholder. But when I use the CSS attribute `margin: 0 auto`, it doesn't do anything. Is there a way to center the whole page?

Comment: You should include some sample HTML that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can't see your code.  The  `margin: 0 auto;` only works on elements with a fixed width.

Comment: There are a lot of answers to this question already. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403736/centering-entire-page-with-css

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    width: 900px; /* or some other fixed-width value */
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; /* reset text-align */
}
```

Edit: guess I should probably show the associated markup as well...

```
...
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- centered content here -->
    </div>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have all your content with in a wrapping div, and have a set width on that element, along with `margin: 0 auto;`

Example:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

- http://davidwalsh.name/horizontally-center-website-structure-css
- http://pmob.co.uk/pob/hoz-vert-center.htm
- http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/center-page-content-horizontally-and-vertically/